# Compare two lists and highlight the difference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two lists which I have to compare.

In the first column are item numbers with letters.

I want to know what the difference between the lists is, one list is the older version and one is the newer version.

- When a row only is in the older version it should be marked red.
- When a row only is in the newer version it should be marked green.

I haven't started writing code for this application because I don't know how I can automate it. At the moment I paste the older list under the newer and filter each row individually and then mark then.. That's not working automatically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe can be achieved with conditional formatting. With the old list in column A and the new list in column B, you can apply conditional formatting with a rule:

- select column B
- create a conditional format with a formula
- use this formula for marking old list values red

=COUNTIF(B:B,A1)

- select the desired format.
- create another formula for marking only new list values green
- use this formula:

=COUNTIF(B:B,A1)=0

- select the desired format.

Note that there are no $ signs in the cell reference.

Adjust the formulas to reflect your lists.

Comment: Oh okay, completely forgot that method... thank you :)